# jQuery.Lazy() - lazy load background image of section with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-lazyload

I want to apply lazy loading for one image with method .lazy() for a section with id. The section has configured background via CSS. Below is code:

HTML

```
  <section id="showcase">
  </section>
```

CSS

```
/* Showcase*/
#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url("../img/example.jpg") no-repeat -300px -500px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(function() {
     $("#showcase").lazy();
  });
 </script>
```

How should I change the code? Because now it doesn´t work. It is working only when I have a code and a tag `<img class="lazy" data-src="../img/example.jpg" />` as you can see in an example below:

http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `JQuery.Lazy` docs and demos in their website, you could load background images by setting the `data-src` attribute to the element on which you want to load the background image.

So in your case you could do as follows:

```
<section id="showcase" data-src="../img/example.jpg"></section>
```

Then you will need to remove the `background-image` definition from the css style.

You can check their working example on [their website](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_load-background-images).

Comment: I tried that but it doesn´t work for me. Here is my code:

HTML
`<section id="showcase" data-src="../img/example.jpg"></section>`

CSS
`#showcase {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: no-repeat -300px -500px;
    background-size: cover;}
`

Javascript
`<script>
  $(function() {
     $("#showcase").lazy();
  });
 </script>
`
Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: @M.Falex can you check the console for errors? Does the background images get loaded? (Check the network tab on the console).

Comment: In console no errors. Yes, the image gets loaded. But it is loaded two times. One time from index.html and second time is initiator jquery.min.js.

Comment: @M.Falex and how does the image gets loaded from the html? The image is not included there or in the css, am i right? Try removing the `background` css property and add the properties using `background-position` and `background-repeat`.

Comment: Now, it is working. Problem was that I forgot on another calling background image in @media segment. Thanks a lot.